# What is the best option to deploy Next.js and Strapi projects to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, deployment, next.js, strapi

Please understand that I am using a translator because I can't speak English.

I want to use Strapi to configure API Server, receive APIs using Nextjs, and create a website that expresses news articles.

News articles are registered daily using the Strapi management panel, and Nextjs should reflect them in real time.

Next.js will also include the ability for users to register, modify, and delete posts. (Board)

Also, in the Expo React Native App, data must be received from Strapi to the API and displayed.

Cloud services must use AWS.

In addition, after development in the local development environment, it must be reviewed by the customer at the test server and updated to the production environment after that.

Therefore, I think we need at least two management servers.

S3 and RDS should also be used.

It's not a very large site.
There are not many users yet.

If I need a docker, I will use it.

- Frontend(Next.js)

1. Amplify
2. Docker -> App Runner
3. Docker -> Fargate
4. EC2

- Backend(Strapi)

1. Amplify
2. Docker -> App Runner
3. Docker -> Fargate
4. EC2

Help me Please!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.